# How to trigger creation of an Activity based on a Contribution being Completed - via CiviRules

Tags: contributions, activities, civirules

The goal is that when a Contribution is Completed then an Activity is created for a Thank You Call.

I tried doing this with 'Contribution is Added' trigger, and setting Contribution Status is Completed as the Condition, but seems this is failing for online ones. It works fine for backend ones I am guessing because with backend the Contribution is set to 'completed' when it is created.

With the online payments is the Contribution record created initially, and then is the status set to 'completed' only after the result comes back from the Payment Processor?

Is there any other Trigger I could run this from? Any other suggestions of how to achieve this?

Comment: I may add this as an Answer but am waiting on testing to be done as I am concerned this may trigger double ups, or create Activities later on if someone causes a Contribution to get modified. There are now 2 rules at play. 
1/ When a Contribution is Added, and has status Completed. 

2/ When a Contribution is Changed, and the status is Completed.

Comment: Pete how about setting the trigger as Membership status changes to New or Current - assuming that the Contribution is for "Member Dues". Also might work if the Contribution is for a paid Event that the user is then Registered for - the trigger is a new Registered Participant.

Comment: You asked "With the online payments is the Contribution record created initially, and then is the status set to 'completed' only after the result comes back from the Payment Processor?" - for Authorize.net the answer is Yes

Comment: thx for confirming latter joe. this is Contribution but not related to membership hence approaches i have tried

Comment: As suggested by others, I would suggest that you have two different rules. From a back-end user perspective I would probably act differently if it is a online payment or a offline payment anyway.

Comment: Just as a WARNING to others, we found that when we had our civirules set up it was triggering rollback of data and hence the contributions were not recorded in civicrm - so we moved away from this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might try with the "contribution is changed" trigger, as you have already done Pete. Alternative is to create your own specific trigger which combines the two? Or find another field to act upon for the online contributions?